# How to revert field back to prior value when another field causes the change in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table that has a JobStartDt column and a TermDt column.  When the termination date is populated, the JobStartDt is overwritten with the termination date (it's like that in the source data that I receive from HR).  I need my SQL script to find the JobStartDt from a previous ReportDate and update the value that changed when the TermDt is populated (there is a record for each individual everyday).  So in the below example, this person has a TermDt of 7/17 - I need the JobStartDt to revert back to 9/16/15.  Is that possible in SQL?  I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.  Thanks in advance!

[image: table records]

Comment: probably a trigger would do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CTE and ROW_NUMBER() funcion, for each employ, find last record before termination and update rows after termination with correct JobStartDt value

```
WITH CTE_BeforeTerm AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM YourTable
  WHERE TermDT IS NULL
)
, CTE_RN
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY ReportDate DESC) RN 
  FROM CTE_BeforeTerm
)
UPDATE t
SET t.JobStartDt = r.JobStartDt
FROM YourTable t 
INNER JOIN CTE_RN r ON r.EmpID = t.EmpID AND r.RN = 1
WHERE t.TermDt IS NOT NULL
```